# Default value script not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, default-value

I am using the following default value script which is working in all browsers I have tested except IE7, where the default value isn't showing for the 'Name' field (It should show 'Name').

I ran the page in IETester and it gave the error: "Expected identifier, string or number" on the line with `};` under `'name[]': 'Name',`. I don't know how to fix this error though.

**EDIT:** This error has now gone, after removing the comma after `'Name'` but I am still not seeing the default value in IE7.  You can see what I mean on [this page](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference/workshops.php).

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var defaults = {
        'name[]': 'Name',
    };

    // separating set and remove
    // note that you could add "defaults" as an arg if you had different
    // defaults for different fieldsets
    var setDefaults = function(inputElements) {
        $(inputElements).each(function() {
            var d = defaults[this.name];
            if (d) {
                // set with jQuery
                // we don't need the data - just check on the class
                $(this).val(d)
                    .addClass('default_value');
            }
        });
    };

    var removeDefaults = function(inputElements) {
        $(inputElements).each(function() {
           if ($(this).hasClass('default_value')) {
                $(this).val('')
                   .removeClass('default_value');
           }
        });
    };

    setDefaults(jQuery('form[name=booking] input'));

    // Toggles 
    $('form[name=booking]').delegate('input', {
        'focus': function() {
            removeDefaults($(this));
        },
        'blur': function() {
            // switch to using .val() for consistency
            if (!$(this).val()) setDefaults(this);
        }
    });
 }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: This is simple debugging; heard of `alert()`? Sticking a few of those in will show you where the problem lies.

Comment: @Matt No, I hadn't heard of alert(). I just ran the page in IETester though, and it gave the error: "Expected identifier, string or number" on the line with `};` under `'name[]': 'Name',`.  I don't know how to fix this error though.

Answer (score 1):

> and it gave the error: "Expected identifier, string or number" on the line with }; under 'name[]': 'Name',. I don't know how to fix this error though.

IE chokes on the trailing comma here:

```
var defaults = {
        'name[]': 'Name',
    };
```

IIRC, rightfully as per the ECMAScript standard. Anyway, just remove the trailing comma and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, the error has now gone in IE7, but I am still not seeing the default value 'Name' in the Name textbox. You can see what I mean if you visit [this page](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference/workshops.php) in IE7.  On all other browsers it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm answering another question of yours lol)

Firstly you'r right in saying the comma broke it, that was incorrect JSON syntax.

Secondly, don't support IE 8 and below (I'm tempted to say don't support IE at all because it sucks, however apparently most of the internet still uses it)

Thirdly, you need to debug this to figure it out, have a look at Parsing JSON ($.parseJSON() i think).

I could show you exactly whats wrong and how to do it, but its more than worthwhile to spend some time practicing debugging javascript by opening up console in your browser and using console.log(VARIABLE); in your JS. Or using alert(VARIABLE) at different times).

eg

```
var setDefaults = function(inputElements) {
        $(inputElements).each(function() {
            var d = defaults[this.name];
            alert(d);
            if (d) {
                // set with jQuery
                // we don't need the data - just check on the class
                $(this).val(d)
                    .addClass('default_value');
            }
        });
    };
```